# A relative path to a file in parent directory in HTML Help Workshop

Tags: html, chm

The relative paths to parent directories either in the *.hhc file or in the html code of the help page .htm does not work in compiled .chm help file.

In this example, file1.htm is in the same directory as the *.hcc file, whereas file2.htm is in other directory that needs to be accessed via parent directory. The HELP Workshop IDE creates following *.hhc:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft&reg; HTML Help Workshop 4.1">
<!-- Sitemap 1.0 -->
</HEAD><BODY>
<OBJECT type="text/site properties">
    <param name="ImageType" value="Folder">
</OBJECT>
<UL>
    <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Name" value="Introduction">
        <param name="Local" value="file1.htm">
        </OBJECT>
    <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Name" value="Topic">
        <param name="Local" value="..\common\file2.htm">
        </OBJECT>
</UL>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The content of the file 1 begins with something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Documentation</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\common\webformat.css" />
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="..\common\WindowControl.java">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <table cols=2>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="bottom"><h2>Overview</h2></td>
        <td align="right"><img src="..\common\images\klein.gif" alt="Logo"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

In the compiled *.chm file the stylesheet is not applied, javascript does not work and images are not displayed. The file2 from the table of content is not accessible as well.

Decompressing the *.chm file with 7zip it is can be seen that the compiler placed all files on the same level, but it left the relative paths in *.htm files and *.hhc files unchanged. That is why they are not accessible:

Help folder hierarchy in the help project:

```
Help
  |-common
  |   |-file2.htm
  |   |-webformat.css
  |   |-WindowControl.java
  |   |-images
  |       |-klein.gif
  |-private
      |-file1.htm
```

And in the decompressed *.chm file hierarchy:

```
Help
  |-file1.htm
  |-file2.htm
  |-webformat.css
  |-WindowControl.java
  |-klein.gif
```

Specifying alternative paths to all relative paths by javascript is a very unclean solution. Moreover, it does not solve the problem of the links in the *.hhc file.

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue can be resolved if there are no paths to parent directories in *.hcc file. This would require the *.hcc to be placed on the highest level in the help project hierarchy. By doing so the relative paths to parent directories in *.htm file would work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Paths should be relative to the root of the directory, and URLs use FORWARD slashes.

All paths in configuration files should be relative to the document root. So if the HELP directory is visible in the CHM, the parent of help is the documentroot, and project files of the CHM project are like help/common/xxx.gif.

Afaik in html files, urls can be relative, maybe it stumbles on the wrong slashes.

(p.s. To view the internal structure of CHMs I use the "chmls" command from Free Pascal, but iirc some of the *nix CHM viewers also display paths)

Comment: There is no .\Help directory in the *.chm. All files are located on the topmost level of the Help.chm. In other words, the Help.chm file is the root directory for file1.htm, instead of the .\private,  .\common directory is also not found in the Help.chm directory. Then the "..\" in the file1.htm would reference the directory of *.chm, that is why the common folder cannot be found on there.

Comment: Hierarchy#1: The problem occurs only if *.hhc file is placed under .\private. If the *.hhc file is placed under .\Help, no parent directory links are needed in the *.hhc file anymore. Links to parent directories in *.htm will work properly in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a work-around for my case. I wanted my project to be available on a network share and so I created my *.hhp file in a directory on that share. I tried for a long time to get the HHP software to find my very simple HTML files, which were in sub directories from the HHP file, but with no success. I ended up creating my HHP project on my local C drive. When I did that, I could access support files from anywhere on our network. It is to my advantage to leave my HTML, CSS etc. files on the share, but they could be anywhere. The only downside is that after you compile your project you have to copy the *.chm file to the location you want it to be, but that is not a major inconvenience. You might even create a simple .bat file for the job.